# ¿Cómo puedo inicializar 4 constructores en class que reciben un solo parámetro?

Tags: c++, constructor

Este es el ejercicio:

> 1.-   REALICE UN PROGRAMA con CLASES , QUE PERMITA REALIZAR LAS CONVERSIONES (son 4 y se tienen que procesar  una tras otra) con DATOS REALES, SEGÚN LA OPCION SELECCIONADA  , de acuerdo a la siguiente lista:
>
> 2. Conversión Pulgadas a milímetros                1 pulgada = 25.4 mm
> 3. Conversión de milímetros a pulgadas.
> 4. Conversión de galones a litros              1 galón = 3.7854 litros
> 5. Conversión de litros a galones
>
> Utilizando:
>
> a)    Constructor
>
> b)    Destructor
>
> c)    Constructor copia

Mi problema es que a la hora de crear un *tercer constructor* (para hacer el inciso 4 del ejercicio),enviar los datos a mi clase me aparece que no puedo sobrecargar el constructor(ya que, anteriormente utilice float y double). No se de que otra manera puedo inicializar el constructor o que otro tipo de dato puedo usar.

El constructor copia lo uso solo para imprimir el resultado en pantalla.
o si alguien tiene otra manera de hacerlo

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define p 25.4
#define g 3.7854

class conversiones{
    private:
        float convertido;
    public:
        conversiones(float recibido);//Constructor0
        conversiones(double recibido);//Constructor1
        conversiones(const conversiones &rC);//constructorCopiaDe los Constructores

        void mostrar();//MostrarDeLosConstructores

        ~conversiones();//Destructor


};
conversiones::conversiones(float recibido):convertido(recibido*p){}//Constructor0
conversiones::conversiones(double recibido):convertido(recibido/p){}//Constructor1

conversiones::conversiones(const conversiones &rC):convertido(rC.convertido){cout<<" Constructor copia ";}//ConstructorCopiaDelosConstructores

void conversiones::mostrar(){//mostrar de los Constructores
 cout<<convertido;
}

conversiones::~conversiones(){}///destructor

main(){
    int opc,salir;
    float dato;
    double dato1;
    cout<<"\t Conversiones";
    do{
        cout<<"\n1.-Pulgadas a milimetros\n2.-Milimetros a pulgadas\n3.-galones a litros\n4.-litros a galones\n5.-Salir\n ";
        cin>>opc;
        system("cls");
        if(opc==1){

            do{
                cout<<"\ningresa pulgada:      ";
                cin>>dato; 
                cout<<"conversion a milimetros: ";
                conversiones c(dato);


                  conversiones c_copy(c);//construsctorCopia
                  c_copy.mostrar();//construsctorCopia

                cout<<"\n\n1.-para otra conversion\n2.-salir\n";
                cin>>salir;

                system("cls");
            }while(salir!=2);

        }
        if(opc==2){
            do{
                cout<<"ingresa milimetros: ";
                cin>>dato1;
                cout<<"conversion a pulgada: ";

                conversiones c1(dato1);

                conversiones c1_copy(c1);//CONSTRUCTOR DE COPIA
                c1_copy.mostrar();

                cout<<"\n\n1.-para otra conversion\n2.-salir\n";
                cin>>salir;
                system("cls");
            }while(salir!=2);
        }
        if(opc==3){
        }
        if(opc==4){
        }
    }while(opc!=5);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

La utilidad de un constructor está en inicializar un objeto para que el mismo sea *usable* desde el primer momento. Para que esta inicialización tenga sentido, los parámetros de entrada también deben tenerlo.

En este caso, asumir que `float` significa pulgadas y `double`, milímetros es absurdo y propenso a errores.

No te están pidiendo que abuses de los constructores sino que diseñes una arquitectura que tenga sentido. Por ejemplo:

```
class Milimetro;

class Pulgada
{
public:
  Pulgada(double valor);

  Pulgada(Milimetro const&);

  Pulgada(Pulgada const&);

  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Pulgada const& pulgadas)
  {
    os << pulgadas.valor_ << " pulgadas";
    return os;
  }

private:
  double valor_;
};

class Milimetro
{
public:
  Milimetro(double valor);

  Milimetro(Milimetro const&);

  Milimetro(Pulgada const&);

  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Milimetro const& mm)
  {
    os << mm.valor_ << " mm";
    return os;
  }

private:
  double valor_;
};


int main()
{
  Pulgada pulgadas(123.45);
  Milimetros milimetros(pulgadas);

  std::cout << pulgadas << '\n' << milimetros << '\n;
}
```